# Select some code, overwrite it by some method name and automatically input previously selected code when finished as parameter [in Intellij]

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I found it hard to formulate this question. Basically I want some new code wrap around the old one. I am used to do this in some editors by simply selecting the old, type the new and once I am done it will automatically replace the old code inside the new. Here is what I mean:

```
int i = 5;
```

Now I want to print this but I forgot to write System.out.prinln() first.

```
int // oeps I forgot that I wanted to System.out.println this statement
```

Now I could of course delete int, write the System.out.println() and write int again. But I don't want that. I want the it remembers what I (over)wrote and put it back as parameter. Here is it visually:

Select the old:

[image]

Start typing and replace the old by doing so:

[image]

Almost finished:

[image]

Here is where the magic happens, the old line appears as paramater input. This is what I want, but it does not work like this automatically:

[image]

Can Intellij already do this? I often start by typing something which is wrapped up by some other in-line code later.

Comment: Why would `System.out.println(int)` ever be what you want?

Comment: Oh shoot, I am so stupid. I meant i. Wow I really need some sleep.

Comment: backspace -> sout -> tab -> ex -> tab. No? Not sure there is a way to do exactly what you want, but you should be able to achieve it in relatively few keystrokes. The [IntelliJ manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/surrounding-blocks-of-code-with-language-constructs.html) doesn't cover this particular use case.

Comment: I changed the pictures. What I want is to use what I typed, and not have to type it again. I could use Ctr + X but even that's not what I want. I want Intellij to recognise that I want to keep what I selected and overwrote. @BoristheSpider thank you. The fact that the intelliJ manual doesn't cover this case seems like a good enough answer. It's a shame. I use this feature a lot in for example latex texstudio.

Comment: Ok, this isn't hard to achieve.  Shift+Ctrl+<-, Ctrl+X, Ctrl-J, "sout", Ctrl-V.  i.e. cut, template, paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sout live template, that's quite easy, at least in version 14: after "exampleInt", type a dot and "sout" will be suggested to you which will do exactly what you want.

For just any method call, that's also easy if you use Complete Statement feature. You start typing before "exampleInt" but not overwriting it. You type what's necessary for the autopopup completion to suggest you the method, e.g. "System.out.priexampleInt". When you have the correct method selected in the popup list, press the shortcut of Edit | Complete Current Statement (Ctrl+Shift+Enter on Windows/Linux). As a result, you get the completed method call with the contents after the caret wrapped as an argument: "System.out.println(exampleInt)".

Answer (score 1):

It seems version 14 has a feture to do this, as described in Peter's answer.

For those of us on older intellij versions, the below may help:

Your best shot is either to "cut and paste": `ctrl X + sout + tab + ctrl V`

Or use smart completion: `DEL + sout + tab + ctrl shift SPACE`